# How to use Css transition?

Tags: css

I have tried Text shorthand using CSS and javascript. as following

HTML

```
<div class=" comment more">Apache Subversion (often abbreviated SVN, after its command name svn) is a software versioning and revision control system distributed as open source under the Apache License. Software developers use Subversion to maintain current and historical versions of files such as source code, web pages, and documentation.Apache Subversion (often abbreviated SVN, after its command name svn) is a software versioning and revision control system distributed as open source under the Apache License. Software developers use Subversion to maintain current and historical versions of files such as source code, web pages, and documentation</div>
```

CSS

```
.comment { //
    width: 100%; //
    background-color: #f0f0f0; //
    margin: 10px;
}

a.morelink {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
var showChar = 100;
        var ellipsestext = "...";
        var moretext = "more";
        var lesstext = "less";
        $('.more').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > showChar) {

                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

                var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }

        });

        $(".morelink").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        });
```

Myfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Balakumar_B/v3xnpxvt/

in above code, if I click more link suddenly show rest of content but I want to show rest of content slowly down. I don't know where to use transition and how to use.. so anyone can suggest trick of use of transition and where to use it?

Comment: I bro I don't more js but I do here on hover effect if you can add in your js than may be helpful :)
https://jsfiddle.net/v3xnpxvt/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use css transitions on display:none; / display:block;

But you can try jQuery slideToggle();
I created a quick fiddle. It's not perfect. just for example

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/v4x564jf/][1]
```

Comment: when I use slideToggle() rest of contents has displayed next line.

Comment: i know it was a quick and dirty solution. let me take a look again